# Is there a better way to write this function?

Tags: c, string

Here is a insert string function,

```
void ins( char * T, size_t ip, char * P)
{
    char temp1[100], temp2[100];

    strncpy(temp1,T,ip);
    strcpy(temp2, &T[ip]);

    strcat(&T[ip], P);
    strcat(&T[sizeof(temp1) + sizeof(P) - 2], temp2);
}
```

Is there a better way to write this function?

Comment: yes, put types on the parameter list.

Comment: yes, by giving meaningful names to the arguments :)

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: yes, don't overrun buffers

Comment: Yes, indent the function body.

Comment: spaces will not go a miss along with indentation

Comment: Would be better to allocate the buffers at run time to make sure they're big enough.

Comment: It cannot be "rewritten", because it is not really "written" yet. What do you think your function is doing? What is it supposed to do? I can see what it is doing from the code, of course. But somehow I don't believe that was the intent. Because what it is doing doesn't seem to make any sense and doesn't seem to agree with the function name.

Comment: Give the FUNCTION a meaningful name, too.  Use strncat, perhaps.  And why are you copying stuff into temp1 and then never making use of temp1 other than to get the size of the variable?

Comment: In any case, both `strncpy` and `strcat` have very few meaningful uses in real code (if any at all). So, yes, it can be rewritten better. (`strncpy` can be used in some narrow set of specific cases, but it is not supposed to be used as a safe string copying function, contrary to a popular belief).

Comment: @Lorem OK, we've had a little bit of fun at your expense. Sorry. What you need to do now is completely edit the question. The question you need to ask goes like this. 1. Define what you want the function to do. Define its inputs and outputs. 2. Show what you have tried. 3. Explain what did not work and what you are unsure about. Ask for advice on how to implement it correctly. You may be best deleting this question and starting again!

Comment: Yes, *<insert suggestion here and get upvoted at least 7 times>*.

Comment: Might be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add an extra argument `maxlen`: the maximal size of str that can be written to. I also modified the return type to something useful.

```
size_t do_insert(char *str, size_t maxlen, size_t where, char *ins)
{
    size_t len_str, len_ins;

    /* these could be arguments, too,
    ** if these are already known by the caller.
    */
    len_str = strlen(str);
    len_ins = strlen(ins);

    /* not enough space: return */
    if (len_str + len_ins >= maxlen)
        return len_str + len_ins;

    /* I don't know what should happen if the place to insert
    ** is beyond the length of str
    ** [ there also is a corner case lurking here if where == len_str]
    */
    if (where > len_str)
        return ???;

    /* make place for the insert by shifting str up.
    ** we move one byte extra: the nul character.
    */
    memmove( str + where + len_ins, str + where, len_ins + 1);

    /* put the insert where it belongs */
    memcpy ( str + where, ins, len_ins );

    /* return the length of the new string */
    return len_str + len_ins;
}
```

**NOTE:** Untested.

Comment: LOL@indent-nazi; I have the habit to put unbraced if () statements on one line ...

Comment: `@indent-nazi` didn't send *me* any notifications. ;) I prefer the two liners - it's much quicker to tell if it's a `for();` or a `for() stmt;`, among other things.